# How to combine values from a response and place the result in a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In the javascript here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/45c4abdad67f5080a52e

there is a result from `street_number` (a house number really) and `route` (pretty much a street name) that is retrieved from the Google Places API.

The values (among the others) are added based on an ID in their respective form fields upon selecting an address from the autocomplete search box.

However, I don't want to store the `street_number` and `route` separately in the DB; I want them to be combined and stored as an "address" in the `address` column of the table.

So, the two values need to be combined and "automatically" placed in the form field with `id = address`. I can't figure out how to to do this. I'm learning Rails and trying to learn javascript is proving more difficult, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addressType = place.address_components[0].types[0] + " " + place.address_components[1].types[0];
```

Unfortunately I cannot see the output that link gives but that is how you create a string in javascript.

Comment: How do I assign that variable to the address form field?